# Android support library not installed in Eclipse 2018

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

So I was getting myself started with android programming, I downloaded the SDK and ADT just like all the other tutorials I've seen on Youtube. Everything was going smoothly until the end of where I was supposed to make my new project:

[image: picture]

It showed a dialog box that which says that I don't have the Android Support Library and that I can't make the project. There are two buttons available which is **"Install/Update"** and **"Check Again"** but when I clicked  "Install/Update" it just shows in the log **"Android Support Jar not found:] C:\java-2018-12\eclipse\v4\android-support-v4.jar"** So I looked for the solution and one said that maybe my Android Support library wasn't installed in my SDK Manager, they said I could find it on "extras" drop down tab but when I got there I didn't find any android support:

[image: picture2]

I installed the what was called **"Android Support Repository"** but it still didn't fix the issue. Can someone help me? I'm desperate.

Comment: Don't use Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse was deprecated a while back as the development environment for Android, so is very likely that most of the libraries you want to use will no longer work with it.

You must use instead [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclid=CjwKCAiA8OjjBRB4EiwAMZe6y_VFlR7rE7PbaU-0qMkymnLmYnU2HhGoWCkZVw2B0I-Oy2PHzXlx5hoC-vkQAvD_BwE).

Comment: I switched to Android Studio now. Thanks.